# Resolution of grub with theme

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, themes, display-resolution

I set up a theme for the grub bootloader and changed the resolution to 1920x1080 with

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32,1024x768,auto
```

So far this works fine.

But after I select the OS, a blank "box" pops up in the center and stays for a couple seconds. The box is smaller than the boot menu, so the boot menu is still visible on the sides. The background color of this box is the one I set in `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub`  with

```
if background_color 99,0,0,0; then
  clear
fi
```

This box (respectively the background color) also appears briefly before the boot menu is visible, but at that point, it's covering the entire screen.

When I press `c` in the boot menu, the same "box" (terminal) also appears with the reduced dimensions.

This is not a big deal, although it is a little bit annoying. So if there is an easy fix for this, I'd like to change it.

PS: If I set `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`, both boot menu and "box" have the same dimensions

This is a picture of the "box" after selecting OS:
[image: image of box]